# mySQL fulltext union search return table name

Tags: mysql

How to return table name in the below mysql fulltext union search?

```
(SELECT title,content,date 
FROM table1 
WHERE (MATCH 
(title,content) 
AGAINST 
('+$boolean' IN BOOLEAN MODE))
) UNION (
SELECT title,content,date 
FROM table2 
WHERE (MATCH 
(title,content) 
AGAINST 
('+$boolean' IN BOOLEAN MODE)))  
Order By date DESC 
LIMIT 0,10
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(SELECT 'table1' as table_name, title,content,date 
FROM table1 
WHERE (MATCH 
(title,content) 
AGAINST 
('+$boolean' IN BOOLEAN MODE))
) UNION (
SELECT 'table2' as table_name, title,content,date 
FROM table2 
WHERE (MATCH 
(title,content) 
AGAINST 
('+$boolean' IN BOOLEAN MODE)))  
Order By date DESC 
LIMIT 0,10
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(SELECT title,content,date, 'Table1' as TableName
FROM table1 
WHERE (MATCH 
(title,content) 
AGAINST 
('+$boolean' IN BOOLEAN MODE))
) UNION (
SELECT title,content,date, 'Table2' as TableName
FROM table2 
WHERE (MATCH 
(title,content) 
AGAINST 
('+$boolean' IN BOOLEAN MODE)))  
Order By date DESC 
LIMIT 0,10
```